# JSP : JSTL's <c:out> tag

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, tags

Writing a JSP page, what exactly does the `<c:out>` do? I've noticed that the following both has the same result:

```
<p>The person's name is <c:out value="${person.name}" /></p>
<p>The person's name is ${person.name}</p>
```

Answer (score 161, accepted):

`c:out` escapes HTML characters so that you can avoid cross-site scripting.

if `person.name = <script>alert("Yo")</script>`

the script will be executed in the second case, but not when using `c:out`

Comment: Only if 'escapeXML' it set to true (not sure if it is by default)

Comment: I believe it is true by default.

Comment: N.B. it escapes XML not HTML. One of the more annoying subtleties of JSTL. I end up always writing my own HTML escape EL fn.

Comment: The attribute name is case sensitive so it's escapeXml="true" not escapeXML

Comment: I have no idea what this answer's code sample is showing- can someone clarify? It mentions a "second case" but I don't see that and I don't see c:out being used in the code.

Comment: @IcedDante: the first case is the first code line mentioned by OP with the c:out.  The second case is OP's second line of code

Comment: @AdamGent What problem do you solve by using your own HTML escape fn?

Comment: @DavidBalažic I don't use JSP anymore but: 1. attribute content escaping is different than text/tag content so you need two different functions even for the case of XML other wise the whitespace is ignored and 2. XML escaping is slightly different than HTML and this is why commons lang and various other libraries have different functions.

Answer (score 130):

As said Will Wagner, in old version of jsp you should always use `c:out` to output dynamic text.

Moreover, using this syntax:

```
<c:out value="${person.name}">No name</c:out>
```

you can display the text "No name" when name is null.

Comment: Agreed, cool.  Thanks for teaching and helping.  I didn't know that either.  Cheers!

Comment: or <c:out value="${person.name}" default="No Name" />

Comment: That is very cool, but I never see this mentioned anywhere. Do you have a link to the spec?

Comment: JSR 52, maintenance release 2, see page 22 "with a body". Link: http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jstl-1.2-mrel2-eval-oth-JSpec/

Comment: @Barett. Cool. I wonder why this never makes any of the tutorials or examples. A more convenient syntax than the default attribute IMO.

Answer (score 7):

`c:out` also has an attribute for assigning a default value if the value of `person.name` happens to be null.

Source: [out (TLDDoc Generated Documentation)](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/out.html)

Answer (score 6):

You can  explicitly enable escaping of Xml entities by using an attribute escapeXml value equals to true. FYI, it's by default "true".

Comment: Some example code would really help make this answer complete.

Answer (score 4):

Older versions of JSP did not support the second syntax.