# Write Static Content With JSTL

Tags: java, jstl, scriptlet

Working on a program and trying to print a static integer from another class. The weird thing is I can do it with scriptlets, but not with JSTL.  Check out the error checking code I just wrote.

```
Comments: <%=Comments.getCommentCount() %> <br />
Comments: ${Comments.getCommentCount()} <br />
Comments: <c:out value="${Comments.getCommentCount()}" /> <br />
Comments: <c:out value="1" />
```

This gives me an HTML output of

```
Comments: 5 <br />
Comments:  <br />
Comments:  <br />
Comments: 1
```

So as you can see only the first and last lines of code work. How can I print out this static variable without scriptlets?

And in my header I have

```
import="org.test.Comments"
```

Comments.java

```
package org.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Comments 
{
    private String name = "";
    private String comment = "";
    private static ArrayList<String> allComments = new ArrayList<String>();


    public void setNewComment(String name, String comment)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.comment = comment;
        allComments.add(getComment());
    }

    public static ArrayList<String> getCommentList()
    {
        Collections.reverse(allComments);
        return allComments;
    }


    public static int getCommentCount()
    {
        return allComments.size();
    }


    public String getComment()
    {
        return String.format("Name:   %s <br />Comment:  %s <p><hr /></p>", name, comment);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need not call the getter inside jstl. just do this

```
<c:out value="${Comments.commentCount}" />
```

assuming your variable name is `commentCount` and not `CommentCount`.

It would work even without `<c:out>`

```
Comments: ${Comments.commentCount} <br />
```

but using `<c:out>` would be better, to avoid cross-site scripting as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291031/jsp-cout-tag)

**UPDATE**

In the class you have mentioned, there is no field with the name commentCount. So it wouldn't work. You can use use jsp fn tag to get a the size of a collection directly inside the jsp.

Include this in the header

```
  <%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
```

and then do this:

```
  <c:out value="${fn:length(allComments)}" />
```

or

```
 Comments: ${fn:length(allComments)} <br />
```

This should work.

Comment: If your Comments class has a field commentCount, it should work. Can you add the jsp and the class to the question?

Comment: Added, and to test our your idea i tried adding this [ private static int one = 1; ] and this [ ${Comments.one} ] as a simple test but it did not work

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a static method, then you could use a custom EL function.
Look at  https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info   near bottom of page.