# Display simple class properties in jsp output with Spring Mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm new in Spring-MVC and I am trying to display a class property that is being assigned to
the model.

I am doing the following with a simple string:

```
model.addAttribute("user", "username" );
```

And it is being display as expected using:

```
<P>  The user is  ${username}. </P>
```

But now I have the following class:

```
public class User { 
          private String name;  
          public User(){
            this.setName("Unknown");
          } 
          public String getName() {
            return name;
          }
          public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
          }
        }
```

And I am trying to display the "Name" property in jsp output without success:

```
     User myuser = new User();
     myuser.setName("CARLOS");
     model.addAttribute("user",myuser);
```

In jsp view I am using:

```
     <p>User name is ${user.Name}</p>
```

Also tried with:

```
     <c:out value="${$user.Name}"></c:out>
```

How can I achieve it?.

Comment: what kind of error you getting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java is case-sensitive.
`name` is not the same as `Name`.

Try `<p>User name is ${user.name}</p>`.

`<c:out value="${user.name}"></c:out>` will also work (without `$` inside parentheses).
Note that using `<c:out>` escapes all HTML characters see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/291047/1995170).

Comment: Ive read It is a must declaring getName method or It crash. Is that true?

Comment: if `name` is `private` field then yes, but why don't you just check it? remove `getName()` and see what happens :)

Answer (score 0):

You have defined the attribute as name. Name wont be found in that case.

```
public class User { 
      private String name;  
      public User(){
        this.setName("Unknown");
      } 
      public String getName() {
        return name;
      }
      public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
      }
    }


<p>User name is ${user.name}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

where you are trying this section:

```
 model.addAttribute("user", "username" );
```

and where you are trying this one:

```
 User myuser = new User();
 myuser.setName("CARLOS");
 model.addAttribute("user",myuser);
```

confusing.. Its ok

//In your controller welcome is a request parameter you have to pass

```
@RequestMapping(value="/welcome", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String welcome(ModelMap model) {
 User myuser = new User();
 myuser.setName("CARLOS");
 model.addAttribute("user",myuser);
 return "/*your jsp file*/";
}
```

In your jsp file

```
<p>User name is ${user}</p>.
```