# XSS vulnerabilities <c:out> tags in JSP pages

Tags: java, jsp, xss, fortify

When I do my fortify scan against my project JSP pages, Fortify complaining more XSS issues to fix the pages. It is complaining most of the places like:`<c:out>` statements. I tried with the function escapeXml from `<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>` using `${fn:escapeXml(path)}` but this is printing entire text as it is.

Actually I have the code in my JSP as given below. I want to fix XSS vulnerability for `<C:out value="${cdt}"/>` tags.

```
<c:set var="checked">
    checked="checked"
</c:set>
<c:set var="cdt" value="" />
<c:set var="dbt" value="" />

<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${casesForm.institutionRepresents == 'C'}">
        <c:set var="cdt" value="${checked}"/>
    </c:when>
    <c:when test="${casesForm.institutionRepresents == 'D'}">
        <c:set var="dbt" value="${checked}"/>
    </c:when>
</c:choose>

<div class="field LINK_show">
    <label><bean:message key="label.institutions" /></label>
    <div style="display:inline;padding-left:10px">
    <input type="radio" name="institutionRepresents" value="A" <c:out value="${cdt}" />><bean:message key="label.credit" /> 
    <input type="radio" name="institutionRepresents" value="I" <c:out value="${dbt}" />><bean:message key="label.debit" /> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there any way to fix XSS vulnerability in `<c:out>` tags?

Answer (score 3):

`<c:out>` already does html escaping, but this is not normally suitable for outputting an attribute. If a user had control over `cdt`, they could modify the attribute name, or value, or add extra attributes. Characters like spaces now become meta characters.

The way you've used it is ok though, because the value of `cdt` can't be directly manipulated by the user, but is set from a safe constant. It can only be `checked="checked"` or empty. You can disable escaping for that value because you want your quotes to be written directly as html.

Comment: you mean that, i should write checked=&quot;checked&quot;.

Comment: @Mdhar9e You can add the escapeXml="false" attribute to the c:out tag. Check the page source in the browser. The output shouldn't have any &quot;

Answer (score 0):

Check out this article on XSS for `<c:out>`

http://tech.finn.no/2011/04/08/xss-protection-whos-responsibility/

Also, here is a related question with a great answer that should help

[JSP : JSTL's <c:out> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291031/jsp-cout-tag)